# How to determine if an element is "positioned"?

Tags: javascript, css

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position), `absolute`-positioned elements are positioned "relative to its closest positioned ancestor".

I know how to traverse up the DOM tree, but how do I determine if an element is considered "positioned" or not?

Comment: What are you hoping to do with this? I can think of some things that could work depending on the circumstances, but not a general solution.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to do this programatically?

Comment: @j08691 Yes... programatically. In JavaScript.

Comment: @BenS. Trying to absolute-position some elements, but a "positioned" ancestor is throwing off my calculations.

Comment: Are you trying to determine if an element is positioned so you can use it in conditional statements?

Comment: @natejms Not really conditional. I just need to determine an element's position relative to the closest positioned ancestor. `getBoundingClientRect` returns it relative to the document, so I have to offset it.

Comment: Not sure why people are hating on this question. Is it not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#positioned-element):

> An element is said to be positioned if its 'position' property has a value other than 'static'.

Comment: Oh really? I thought just `relative` and `absolute` were positioned. `fixed` and `sticky` are too? Thanks for the official reference

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little example of how to get the absolute position of an element:

```js
let target = document.getElementById('e');


let p = target;
let pos;
do {
  p = p.parentElement;
  pos = window.getComputedStyle(p).getPropertyValue("position");
} while (p.parentElement && pos === 'static');



let rect = target.getBoundingClientRect();
let offset = p.getBoundingClientRect();



let output = document.getElementById('o');

let x = rect.left - offset.left;
let y = rect.top - offset.top;

output.innerText = `Rect: ${rect.left}, ${rect.top}
Offset: ${offset.left}, ${offset.top}
Fixed: ${x}, ${y}
`;

let overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');



Object.assign(overlay.style, {
  left: `${x}px`,
  top: `${y + rect.height}px`,
})
```

```css
#a {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px 10px 2px 8px;
}

#b {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 2px 7px 5px 6px;
  position: relative;
}

#c {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 9px 10px 4px 8px;
}

#d {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  padding: 1px 6px 9px 18px;
}

#e {
  border: 1px solid cyan;
  padding: 4px 12px 2px 3px;
}

output {
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#overlay {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, .8);
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">
    <div id="c">
      <div id="d">
        <div id="e">
          Hello
          <div id="overlay">Positioned directly under cyan box</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>



<output id="o">
```